# PHP: preg_match limit anchor text in form textarea

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to limit the number of Anchor text in a textarea to 1.

After a few weeks' research, I could not do that using this code

```
    if(preg_match('/.*http:\//', $content->description) > 1) {
    else 'You can not submit Anchor text more than one times';
}

<textarea>
<a href="https://example.com/">Anchor text 1</a>
<a href="http://example2.com/">Anchor text 2</a>
<a href="https://www.example3.com/">Anchor text 3</a>
<a href="http://www.example4.com/">Anchor text 4</a>
Not Anchor text http://www.example.com/
</textarea>
```

How can limit submission HTML tag `<a>` in form textarea using "preg_match"?

Comment: you could just use `substr_count()` but i can think of ways around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content->description);

if ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->length > 1 ) {
    ...
```